# grouping inside xsl file won't give me any results

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi and thanks for reading this.
I have a problem with making an xsl file.
So here is what I need to do.

I need an xsl file that takes data out of the xml file (MySQL query return) and translate it to a xml structure usable in DHTMLX tree view.

Here is the xml file from where I have to start.

```
<dbqueries>
    <environment>PRD</environment>
    <label>ConfigNewReport</label>
    <description>ConfigNewReport</description>
    <dbquery id="algemeen_overview">
        <descriptor>
            <database>dbnode</database>
            <originalquery>
SELECT * FROM local_parser_lrf_man where rapport is not null
</originalquery>
            <querystring>
SELECT * FROM local_parser_lrf_man where rapport is not null
</querystring>
        </descriptor>
        <columns>
            <column name="Path" type="VARCHAR" />
            <column name="File" type="VARCHAR" />
            <column name="DBWEB" type="VARCHAR" />
            <column name="XMLWEB" type="VARCHAR" />
            <column name="rapport" type="VARCHAR" />
            <column name="niveau" type="INT" />
            <column name="rapport_nr" type="INT" />
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" File="CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2014_LBA.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\trends.xml" File="trends.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/trends_new.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/trendsData.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2014.xml" File="CODIR_2014.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2014.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\COCKPIT.xml" File="COCKPIT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/COKPIT.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="0" rapport_nr="73" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\MONITORING_BCOM_PR.xml" File="MONITORING_BCOM_PR.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/MONITORING_BCOM_PR.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/MONITORING_BCOM_PR.xsl" rapport="PR to COMMIT" niveau="0" rapport_nr="74" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2016_XLS.xml" File="CODIR_2016_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2016.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2016_XLS.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2013_XLS.xml" File="CODIR_2013_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2013_XLS.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2013.xml" File="CODIR_2013.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2013.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR.xml" File="CODIR.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="0" rapport_nr="45" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\COKPIT_LAYOUT.xml" File="COKPIT_LAYOUT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/COKPIT_LAYOUT.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\EDA.xml" File="EDA.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/EDA.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/EDA.xsl" rapport="Rapport EDA" niveau="0" rapport_nr="84" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\trends1.xml" File="trends1.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/trends_new.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/trendsData1.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2016.xml" File="CODIR_2016.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2016.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2016.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_XLS.xml" File="CODIR_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_XLS.xsl" rapport="CoDir" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xml" File="CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\BFB\COKPIT_XLS.xml" File="COKPIT_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/BFB/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xml" XMLWEB="BFB/XSL/COKPIT_XLS.xsl" rapport="COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\NC_BFAL_BIS.xml" File="NC_BFAL_BIS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/NC_BFAL_BIS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/NC_BFAL_BIS.xsl" rapport="credit notes and their available(STATUS U,G,M,S,W,R)" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ORDER_EVOL_BIS.xml" File="ORDER_EVOL_BIS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ORDER_EVOL.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ORDER_EVOL_BIS.xsl" rapport="Evolution orders by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) " niveau="0" rapport_nr="29" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DIM_VISUM.xml" File="DIM_VISUM.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xsl" rapport="visum diminutions" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DIM_VISUM_1.xml" File="DIM_VISUM_1.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DIM_VISUM_1.xsl" rapport="visum diminutions" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\IR.xml" File="IR.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ILIAS_ROLE.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/IR.xsl" rapport="ILIAS role by user" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ILIAS_ROL_DET.xml" File="ILIAS_ROL_DET.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ILIAS_ROLE.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ILIAS_ROL_DET.xsl" rapport="ILIAS role by user" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DIM_VISUM_XLS.xml" File="DIM_VISUM_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DIM_VISUM_XLS.xsl" rapport="visum diminutions" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU.xml" File="DU.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DU.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BFB_SIT_LEVEL_3.xml" File="BFB_SIT_LEVEL_3.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_3.xsl" rapport="Analytic Image - System" niveau="4" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\PAYMENT_TERM_REGROUP.xml" File="PAYMENT_TERM_REGROUP.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM_REGROUP.xsl" rapport="PAYMENT_TERM" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DIM_VISUM_HEAD.xml" File="DIM_VISUM_HEAD.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DIM_VISUM_HEAD.xsl" rapport="visum diminutions" niveau="0" rapport_nr="26" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\INV_COUNT.xml" File="INV_COUNT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/INV_BIS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/INV_COUNT.xsl" rapport="PINV counting per STATUS and YEAR " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\COM_ORD_EVOL.xml" File="COM_ORD_EVOL.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/tab.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/COM_ORD_EVOL.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="0" rapport_nr="24" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU_XLS.xml" File="DU_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DU.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU_XLS.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ORD_MONTH.xml" File="ORD_MONTH.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ORD_MONTH1.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ORD_MONTH.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\INVOICE_STAT_PART2.xml" File="INVOICE_STAT_PART2.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/INVOICE_STAT.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/INVOICE_STAT_PART2.xsl" rapport="Payment Terms and To late payment" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DC_DETAIL.xml" File="DC_DETAIL.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DC.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DC_DETAIL.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of credit demands by LBA" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU_HEAD.xml" File="DU_HEAD.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/tab.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU_HEAD.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="0" rapport_nr="35" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BUD_OVERVIEW_XLS.xml" File="BUD_OVERVIEW_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_XLS.xsl" rapport="Level DOPA BA LBA -Sum of invoice's amount (Free margin) " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BUD_OVERVIEW_INV_XLS.xml" File="BUD_OVERVIEW_INV_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_INV.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_INV_XLS.xsl" rapport="Level DOPA BA LBA -Sum of invoice's amount (Free margin) " niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\COM_MONTH.xml" File="COM_MONTH.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/COM_MONTH1.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/COM_MONTH.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\CONTRAT_XLS.xml" File="CONTRAT_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/Contrat.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/CONTRAT_XLS.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of PAID/ORDERED_TO_PAY invoices by FIRM/CONTRACT (PAYMENT YEAR&gt;2011) " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\COM_EVOL_PDF1.xml" File="COM_EVOL_PDF1.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/COM_EVOL_PDF1.xml" XMLWEB="DB" rapport="Weekly budget report (DGMR)" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BUD_OVERVIEW_INV.xml" File="BUD_OVERVIEW_INV.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_INV.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_INV.xsl" rapport="Level DOPA BA LBA -Sum of invoice's amount (Free margin) " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BFB_SIT.xml" File="BFB_SIT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BFB_SIT.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BFB_SIT1.xsl" rapport="Analytic Image - System" niveau="4" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\CVE.xml" File="CVE.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/tab.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/CVE.xsl" rapport="Compensation - Evolution of Fiches A and B" niveau="0" rapport_nr="69" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\SIBIS_REC.xml" File="SIBIS_REC.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/SIBIS_REC.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/SIBIS_REC.xsl" rapport="Sit REC SIBIS (BF_REC_SIT_V10 from Business Object)" niveau="0" rapport_nr="71" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU_CC_XLS.xml" File="DU_CC_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DU.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU_CC_XLS.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\FINAMED.xml" File="FINAMED.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/FINAMED.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/FINAMED.xsl" rapport="Fin@Med - Pers Monitoring" niveau="0" rapport_nr="70" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BFB_SIT_LEVEL_4.xml" File="BFB_SIT_LEVEL_4.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_4.xsl" rapport="Analytic Image - System" niveau="5" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\AGGR_10_DAYS_DET_XLS.xml" File="AGGR_10_DAYS_DET_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/AGGR_10_DAYS_DET_XLS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/AGGR_10_DAYS_DET_XLS.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\AGGR_MONTH_XLS.xml" File="AGGR_MONTH_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/AGGR_MONTH2_XLS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/AGGR_MONTH_XLS.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\SIBIS_REC_XLS.xml" File="SIBIS_REC_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/SIBIS_REC.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/SIBIS_REC_XLS.xsl" rapport="Sit REC SIBIS (BF_REC_SIT_V10 from Business Object)" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU_CC.xml" File="DU_CC.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DU.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU_CC.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ORDER_EVOL_BIS_XLS.xml" File="ORDER_EVOL_BIS_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ORDER_EVOL.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ORDER_EVOL_BIS_XLS.xsl" rapport="Evolution orders by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BUD_OVERVIEW_BIS.xml" File="BUD_OVERVIEW_BIS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BUD_OVERVIEW_BIS.xsl" rapport="Level DOPA BA LBA -Sum of invoice's amount (Free margin) " niveau="0" rapport_nr="23" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DIM_VISUM_TOT.xml" File="DIM_VISUM_TOT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DIM_VISUM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DIM_VISUM_TOT.xsl" rapport="visum diminutions" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\PAYMENT_TERM_HEAD.xml" File="PAYMENT_TERM_HEAD.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/tab.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM_HEAD.xsl" rapport="PAYMENT_TERM" niveau="0" rapport_nr="55" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2_1.xml" File="BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2_1.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2_1.xsl" rapport="Analytic Image - System" niveau="3" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\INV_COUNT_XLS.xml" File="INV_COUNT_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/INV_BIS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/INV_COUNT_XLS.xsl" rapport="PINV counting per STATUS and YEAR " niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\IR_DET.xml" File="IR_DET.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ILIAS_ROLE.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/IR_DET.xsl" rapport="ILIAS role by user" niveau="3" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DC_DETAIL_XLS.xml" File="DC_DETAIL_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DC.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DC_DETAIL_XLS.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of credit demands by LBA" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\VISA_BIS.xml" File="VISA_BIS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/VISA_BIS.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/VISA_BIS.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of visum + available level imputation line (new version!) " niveau="0" rapport_nr="9" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DU_UNIT.xml" File="DU_UNIT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DU.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DU_UNIT.xsl" rapport="Rights of use" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\Contrat.xml" File="Contrat.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/Contrat.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/Contrat.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of PAID/ORDERED_TO_PAY invoices by FIRM/CONTRACT (PAYMENT YEAR&gt;2011) " niveau="1" rapport_nr="8" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\FED_BIS.xml" File="FED_BIS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/FEDCOM_REQUEST.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/FED_BIS.xsl" rapport="List of requests for (new) suppliers" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\PAYMENT_TERM.xml" File="PAYMENT_TERM.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM.xsl" rapport="PAYMENT_TERM" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BFB_SIT_LEVEL_5.xml" File="BFB_SIT_LEVEL_5.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_2.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BFB_SIT_LEVEL_5.xsl" rapport="Analytic Image - System" niveau="6" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\INVOICE_STAT_HEAD.xml" File="INVOICE_STAT_HEAD.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/INVOICE_STAT.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/INVOICE_STAT_HEAD.xsl" rapport="Payment Terms and To late payment" niveau="0" rapport_nr="64" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\PAYMENT_TERM_INV.xml" File="PAYMENT_TERM_INV.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM_DETAIL.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/PAYMENT_TERM_INV.xsl" rapport="PAYMENT_TERM" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\BA_DOPA_INCOME_NEW.xml" File="BA_DOPA_INCOME_NEW.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/BA_DOPA_INCOME.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/BA_DOPA_INCOME_NEW.xsl" rapport="Income/debt level YEAR-BA-DOPA-LBA" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\SYNTH_WEEK.xml" File="SYNTH_WEEK.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/SYNTH_WEEK1.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/SYNTH_WEEK.xsl" rapport="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\DC.xml" File="DC.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/DC.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/DC.xsl" rapport="Monitoring of credit demands by LBA" niveau="0" rapport_nr="10" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ultimate\DEBT_EVOL_XLS_ULTIMATE.xml" File="DEBT_EVOL_XLS_ULTIMATE.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ultimate/DEBT_MONTH_ULTIMATE.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ultimate/xsl/DEBT_EVOL_XLS_ULTIMATE.xsl" rapport="Evolution debt by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) or by visum(global view)" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ultimate\DEBT_MONTH_PR_ULTIMATE.xml" File="DEBT_MONTH_PR_ULTIMATE.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/ultimate/DEBT_MONTH_ULTIMATE.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ultimate/xsl/DEBT_MONTH_PR_ULTIMATE.xsl" rapport="Evolution debt by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) or by visum(global view)" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Rapports\ultimate\DEBT_EVOL_ULTIMATE.xml" File="DEBT_EVOL_ULTIMATE.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Rapports/tab.xml" XMLWEB="Rapports/ultimate/xsl/DEBT_EVOL_ULTIMATE.xsl" rapport="Evolution debt by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) or by visum(global view)" niveau="0" rapport_nr="28" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L_XLS.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L_XLS.xsl" rapport="Consumption in COM and ORD on target credit" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Secure/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR.xsl" rapport="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR (without LBA 82,84)" niveau="0" rapport_nr="37" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_VP_DOPABA_CAT.xml" File="BP_VP_DOPABA_CAT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_VP_DOPABA.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_VP_DOPABA_CAT.xsl" rapport="Follow-up imputation lines group by DOPABA CAT" niveau="0" rapport_nr="5" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_VP_DOPABA.xml" File="BP_VP_DOPABA.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_VP_DOPABA.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_VP_DOPABA.xsl" rapport="Follow-up imputation lines group by DOPABA" niveau="0" rapport_nr="4" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2_NEW.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2.xsl" rapport="Blocage BFB by DOPA BA LBA" niveau="0" rapport_nr="39" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Secure/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA.xsl" rapport="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA (without LBA 82,84)" niveau="0" rapport_nr="1" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2_XLS.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2_XLS_NEW.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BLOC_2_XLS.xsl" rapport="Blocage BFB by DOPA BA LBA" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Secure/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xsl" rapport="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR (without LBA 82,84)" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_BFA-L.xsl" rapport="Consumption in COM and ORD on target credit" niveau="0" rapport_nr="19" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\MRSYN\BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_CAT.xml" File="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_CAT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Secure/MRSYN/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_CAT.xml" XMLWEB="MRSYN/XSL/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_CAT.xsl" rapport="BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_CAT (without LBA 82,84)" niveau="0" rapport_nr="3" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\research_invoice\grid_nc.xml" File="grid_nc.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/research_invoice/grid_nc.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/research_invoice/XSL/grid_nc.xsl" rapport="research_invoice" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" File="CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/CODIR_2014_LBA.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\trends.xml" File="trends.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/trends_new.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/trendsData.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\COCKPIT.xml" File="COCKPIT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/COKPIT.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="0" rapport_nr="96" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\COKPIT_LAYOUT.xml" File="COKPIT_LAYOUT.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/COKPIT_LAYOUT.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\trends1.xml" File="trends1.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/trends_new.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/trendsData1.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\change_range.xml" File="change_range.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/change_range.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\CODIR_XLS.xml" File="CODIR_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/CODIR_XLS.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xml" File="CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/CODIR_2014_LBA.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/CODIR_2014_LBA_GRAPH.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\BFB\COKPIT_XLS.xml" File="COKPIT_XLS.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/BFB/BP_BG_TOT_DOPABA_PR_XLS.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/BFB/XSL/COKPIT_XLS.xsl" rapport="test COCKPIT DGBF" niveau="2" rapport_nr="" />
            <row Path="\lrf_descriptors\XMLWeb\Vanlandschoot\research_invoice\CboFirm.xml" File="CboFirm.xml" DBWEB="DBWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/Vanlandschoot/research_invoice/CboFirm.xml" XMLWEB="Vanlandschoot/research_invoice/XSL/CboFirm.xsl" rapport="research_invoice" niveau="1" rapport_nr="" />
        </rows>
    </dbquery>
</dbqueries>
```

I need to group the File names based on the report name and set them in a item tag called XMLWEB

The result should be for each rapport

```
<tree>
    <item id="rapport_nr" text="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text="COM_WEEK.xml"/>
         <item text="SYNTH_MONTH.xml"/>
         <item text="ORD_WEEK.xml"/>
         <item text="ORD_MONTH.xml"/>
         .....
      </item>
   </item>
</tree>
```

This is the result I get

```
<tree>
    <item id="rapport_nr" text="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text=""/>
      </item>
   </item>
</tree>
```

What I have for now is the first and second part. I can't seem to find a way to loop over the rows for the most inner item parts.

This is the code I have. Tried it with a xsl:for-each but it doesn't work. So the problem is with step 3.

any help would be welcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- ENKEL CONVERSIE-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output version="1.0" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">           
    <tree>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//dbquery[@id='algemeen_overview']/rows/row"/>
    </tree>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//dbquery[@id='algemeen_overview']/rows/row">
<!-- step 1: each report item tag with ID from table DGBF_report_list and get name of report-->        
    <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@rapport_nr"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="@rapport"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
<!-- End step 1 -->        
<!-- step 2: make new "folder" XMLWEB. -->
        <xsl:element name="item">
            <xsl:attribute name="text">XMLWEB</xsl:attribute>
<!-- step 3: loop to find all filles used in the same report -->                                                
                <xsl:for-each select="@rapport">
                    <xsl:element name="item">
                        <xsl:attribute name="text">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@File"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
<!-- END STEP 3 -->
        </xsl:element>
<!-- EINDE STEP 2 -->                     
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Thanks to michael.hor257k I came to the solution.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/dbqueries">
    <tree>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dbquery/rows/row" group-by="@rapport">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@rapport_nr"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="text">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                <item text="XMLWEB">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()" >
                        <item text="{@File}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </item> 
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </tree>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show us your XML input (if necessary, use the *identity transform* template to produce it).

Comment: I added some more info to the question. 
@Parfait it's not the XSLT that runs the query. It's a XML file. The XSLT file is only to restructure the existing xml file.

Comment: The added info tells me nothing. We need to see the raw XML returned from your query.

Comment: This is the only info and files whe have to work with. So basicly we need to transform the last code block in this question into the first code block in this question.
Anyway already thanks alot for taking time to find an answer

Comment: If I take "the last code block in this question" and apply your XSLT to it, I don't get the result that you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still find the question very confusing, but in the interest of moving forward, consider this as a starting point:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/dbqueries">
    <tree>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dbquery/rows/row" group-by="@rapport">
            <item id="rapport_nr" text="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <item text="XMLWEB">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()" >
                        <item text="{@File}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </item> 
            </item> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </tree>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This groups the `row` elements by their `rapport` attribute, creates an outer and an inner `item` wrapper for each group, and lists each group member's `File` attribute.

Applied to the given example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tree>
   <item id="rapport_nr" text="Evolution COM/ORD by month or days">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text="COM_WEEK.xml"/>
         <item text="SYNTH_MONTH.xml"/>
         <item text="ORD_WEEK.xml"/>
         <item text="ORD_MONTH.xml"/>
         <item text="COM_MONTH.xml"/>
         <item text="AGGR_10_DAYS_DET_XLS.xml"/>
         <item text="AGGR_MONTH_XLS.xml"/>
         <item text="SYNTH_WEEK.xml"/>
         <item text="COM_ORD_EVOL.xml"/>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item id="rapport_nr" text="Evolution orders by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) ">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text="ORDER_EVOL_BIS_XLS.xml"/>
         <item text="ORDER_EVOL_BIS.xml"/>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item id="rapport_nr"
         text="Evolution debt by DOPA-BA-LBA-CT(monthly) or by visum(global view)">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text="DEBT_EVOL_XLS_ULTIMATE.xml"/>
         <item text="DEBT_MONTH_PR_ULTIMATE.xml"/>
         <item text="DEBT_VISUM_ULTIMATE.xml"/>
         <item text="DEBT_MONTH_ULTIMATE.xml"/>
         <item text="DEBT_EVOL_ULTIMATE.xml"/>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item id="rapport_nr" text="Compensation - Evolution of Fiches A and B">
      <item text="XMLWEB">
         <item text="CVE.xml"/>
      </item>
   </item>
</tree>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGa

Comment: Thx alot. This is not the starting point THIS is the solution to my problem. I only have to expand it a bit more to get 2 more different <item text="XMLWEB"> but that is just a matter of redoing the part you did. Now I have an' off toppic" question. You said the question is confusing, Now that you know the answer what could I do to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: @Sven The question should have started with the input XML that you have added at the end. It should have included a short explanation of the required task (similar to the way I have explained what my XSLT code actually does). Then it should have shown the expected output of transforming the given XML. And I still don't understand what you tried to do in your XSLT attempt. And of course the fact that it doesn't produce the claimed result adds to the confusion. HTH.

Comment: @michal.hor257k Ah oke anway thx alot. btw I tried that XSLtransform site and I can reproduce the problem. [http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKc](http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKc)